# Why is the jQuery BlockUI plugin blocking the entire page?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-blockui

In my Ruby on Rails app, I am attempting to block a single form like this:

```
$('#<%= @category.key %> .save').click(function() {
  $('#<%= @category.key %> .assignment_form_new').block({ message: null });
});
```

However when I call this function on the element, it blocks the whole page instead of blocking just the form. If you would like, I can provide more code.

So as you can see in this image, the bottom row is a new assignment row, and that is the specific form I'm trying to block:

[image]

However when calling the block function on this specific row, it blocks almost the entire page:

[image]

Any ideas on what could be causing this? I know the selector I'm using is unique so it's not selecting something else that is using the same ID and class.

**PROGRESS UPDATE 1:** So as you may notice from the screenshots, I am using jQuery UI Tabs. It looks like when I call block on just the new assignment form, it blocks jQuery UI Tabs instead, which obviously blocks everything inside of it too.

Just as a demonstration, I would like to also show you that this isn't an issue with event bubbling, because I can call the function in the console and it will still block the jQuery UI Tabs:

[image]

**PROGRESS UPDATE 2:** Think I figured out the issue. The DIVs that I am using are being displayed as 'table', 'table-row', and 'table-cell', and apparently blockUI can't block table elements. So I have to figure out a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not used this.

```
$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```

If it is not the case there might be the problem of event bubbling. 
In that case you could use this:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatley, I have never used that first statement in my code. Also, I don't think it's an issue with event bubbling because when I put the line: "$('.assignment_form_new').block({ message: null });" in my developer console, it will still block almost the whole page.

Comment: which version of Jquery BlockUI you are using? I am using Version 2.70.0-2014.11.23 and it works fine for me.

Comment: I'm using the latest version that I downloaded right off their website.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've figured it out. Never try to block a table row with jQuery blockUI because it doesn't work. The alternative approach I took is to loop through and block each cell in the table row.